# The [spelling] needs to be changed

Tags: discussion, retag-request

[spell-checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spell-checking) and [spelling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spelling) refer to the same concept (even the same Wikipedia article). Spell-checking is the more commonly used tag, so it should remain.

Comment: @yellowantphil I think [tag:naming-conventions] covers that particular use case.